# Parse saveInBackground when iPhone is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, save, request

I want to be able to save a users information while the iOS device is locked. I'm using background modes but the saveInBackground only seems to work for about 5 seconds then it stops saving. When re open the app it saves them all at once. is there a way to keep them saving when it's locked?

Thanks

Comment: I ran into a similar problem.  It's really annoying, but I found that using Parse Cloud Code was the way to go.  So instead of using saveInBackground in the app itself, pass the data to a Cloud Code function that does the saving.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you have any examples of cloud code that might suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloud Code (JS) **

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createSale", function(request, response) {
  var SaleClass = Parse.Object.extend("Sale");
  var sale = new SaleClass();
  sale.set("contractorId", request.params.contractorId);
  sale.set("subtotal", request.params.subtotal);
  sale.save(null, {
  success: function (sale) {
                    console.log(responseData);
                    response.success(responseData);
                  },
                  error: function (error) {
                    response.error(error);
                    console.log(error);
                  }
                });
 });
```

**Share Instance of ParseCloudFunctions (Obj-C)**

I created a class that holds all my Parse Cloud Code Functions.  I create a shared instance of this class and have an instance method that calls the Parse Cloud Code:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

+ (ParseCloudFunctions *) sharedInstance {
    static ParseCloudFunctions *sharedInstance;
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ParseCloudFunctions alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
 }

- (void) createSaleWithParameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters block:(void (^)(id object, NSError *error)) block{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"createSale" withParameters:parameters block:block];
}
```

Whenever you want call the parse cloud code, you just do:

```
 NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"contratorId":contractorId,
                                 @"subtotal":subtotal,
                                 };

    [[ParseCloudFunctions sharedInstance] createSaleWithParameters:parameters block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            //Handle Error
        }
        if(object){
            //Do stuff
        }
    }];
```

The saving is handled on the server side, so you just need a bit of time to call the cloud code and you'll be good.

Comment: Can you get a users location using Parse Cloud Code? You see that is what i am trying to do. get the users location while the phone is locked and send it to the cloud.

Comment: You have to have the user after to location services in background always, not just when in use. When the location changes, pass the longitude and latitude to thre parse cloud code function